# Registered Symbol ® in text message in mobileconnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am creating a text message in which i need a ® (Registered) symbol.
I tried using the `%%=char(169)=%%` where 169 is the ASCII code for the registered symbol. But by using this I get the response:

> there was an error processing your request

Can someone please suggest how to add registered symbol to text message. Also please advise if I can superscript the registered symbol.

Working Version:

```
Thank you for your request. Here is a link to download the XXX Mobile App.%%=char(10)=%%
iOS: http://apple.co/XXX%%=char(10)=%%
Android: http://xxx/xxx
```

Not Working Version:

```
%%[
SET @Reg = Char(174)
SET @message = Concat("Thank you for your request. Here is a link to download the XXX",@Reg)
]%%
%%=v(@message)=%% Mobile App.%%=char(10)=%%
iOS: http://apple.co/XXX%%=char(10)=%%
Android: http://xxx/xxx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come across this situation before where MobileConnect Outbound SMS wouldn't respect the spaces and I guess your reg trademark is related to same issue.

The workaround this is by using the ASCII characters within the SMS. [Here](http://www.asciitable.com/) is the table of the ASCII characters.

Also I'd use the AMPscript **[Char](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Char.htm)** that returns the ASCII character specified by the ASCII character code in the first parameter.

Example:

```
%%[
SET @Reg = Char(174)

SET @message = Concat("This is a sample SMS to check the registered symbol.",@Reg)
]%%
%%=v(@message)=%%
```

> Note: Superscript is part of the html tag and is not supported in SMS
>   format.

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Above solution does not work. i get the same error message response.

Comment: @kunal I have test this myself in MobileConnect and I didn't face any issue. Could you please explain more on how you're testing the SMS?

Comment: i am sending the keyword to the short code and getting an a reply 'there was an error processing your request'. When i remove the registered trademark from the sms and try again i get the desired message

Comment: @kunalgidwani Is there any chance you can update your post with the actual code you're using in the sms?

Comment: Updating the code above

Comment: Again, I copied your code and test it. I have successfully received the sms with the reg symbol. I can attach the screen shot if you want. thanks

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot of the message

Comment: @kunalgidwani updated the solution with the screenshot

Comment: The solution works but the Char function is using HTML entity numbers - not ASCII codes. Here's a link where 174 is an html entity number https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Only some country/code combos support the use of non-GSM characters. Most only support GSM 7 bit alphabet characters - the registered Mark isn't one

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7-bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_.2F_GSM_03.38

According to Marketing Cloud documentation

You can only use GSM 3.38 and UTF-16 characters in SMS message content.

You could try : 0x00AE
However if your country/code doesn't support it then you are stuck